# How can I update the bundler version used by RubyMine?

Tags: bundler, rubymine

When I try to run a spec in RubyMine, or try to do a 'bundle install' from RubyMine, I get an error

> This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler. Perhaps you need
>   to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

RubyMine is using bundler 1.12.5, but my project is requiring 1.14.6 in the Gemfile.lock.
How can I update the bundler version that RubyMine uses?
Note: I can do this from the bash console with no issue, but that does not affect RubyMine. This is purely a RubyMine issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

bundler can be used from `rvm` or `rbenv` on your computer. You can learn which bundler that you use with running this command:

```
> which bundler
```

To change bundler that rubymine uses, open **Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Ruby SDK and Gems**. Then select the appropriate version of bundler for rubymine.

[image]

Comment: It does not select the bundler version. It is only showing bundle list. In my case, as the project is so specific I deleted the undesired version. Rubymine started using the remain version. It is like rubymine does not allow you to select it on the IDE. It uses the most recent version.

Answer (score 2):

*Updated*: [Excellent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50465558/4812102):

"For Rubymine 18.1 and above, double-press ctrl will open Run Anything dialog box. In it, type command you want to run (In your case 'gem install bundler') and press enter. Next it will ask for any extra arguments to be passed, and after it will execute the command in Rubymine."

*What else could be wrong* (from the original version of my answer):

Chances are that RubyMine and rvm or rbenv in bash console are using different gemsets.

To see the current gemset, run in the bash console:

`$ rvm gemset name`

To switch to the same gemset that's set in Rubymine:

`$ rvm use 2.3.3@current-gemset`

Then run `$ gem install bunler` - it will be installed to the `current-gemset` and RubbyMine will start using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Terminal in RubyMine and do a `gem install bundler` to get the newest version.