# How do I run 'gem install bundler' in RubyMine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, rubymine

I'm having trouble with updating Ruby in my RubyMine IDE.

I get an error reporting that I need to run `gem bundle install` but I haven't found a place in my IDE to run that command.

I have run it in my Ubuntu console and everything works fine, but I can't find a console in the IDE that I can use to run the command and update that environment. I assume there's an easy solution, but google has not helped much in finding it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to run that from a command prompt. You could click Terminal (which is probably nested at the bottom of the screen) then you literally type in `gem install bundler` but if you have already installed it I am not sure why you would need to install it again.

Comment: There is conflict between your question title "gem install bundler" and your question content "gem bundle install".

Answer (score 2):

For Rubymine **18.1** and above, ***double-press ctrl*** will open **Run Anything** dialog box. In it, type command you want to run (In your case 'gem install bundler') and press enter. Next it will ask for any extra arguments to be passed, and after it will execute the command in Rubymine.